# vinyl 1/2in tubing for supply to faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet

Running vinyl tubing from a foot pump to a faucet.  I have the standard compression supply hose that came with the faucet.  What's the easiest way to marry the 2?  I want to attach that supply hose to the vinyl tubing. a male compression to 1/2in barbed fitting?  does such a thing exist?  I tried a regular compression adapter for size alone but it leaks I'm guessing because I need the barbs for the vinyl instead of the threads with a clamp.
[image]

Comment: Is that not working in the picture?  Or is that an example of what you're trying to duplicate?

Comment: that was my old setup not working.  it leaks where the vinyl connects at the bottom.  I'm guessing sliding the tubing over the brass adapter's threads and then clamping is not watertight.  that's why I'm thinking of a compression to barb adapter.  if that's what you'd call it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now. Yea, the threads are a spiral, so they will always drip if you try to clamp over them like that.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you might be able to find one fitting do this connection, but it's going to be much easier to use two that are very common at home stores.  First, you will need a 3/8" compression to 1/4" MIP (male pipe thread) adapter and then a 1/4" FIP (female pipe) to 1/4" barb (or whatever size you need) adapter.

These two adapters will connect with the common pipe threads (with teflon tape) and provide the barb you need on one side, and the compression fitting needed for the faucet.

[image: Barb fitting]

*[Barb fitting](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-4-in-x-1-4-in-FIP-Lead-Free-Brass-Hose-Barb-Adapter-Fitting-800209/300096277)*

[image: Compression fitting]

*[Compression fitting](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-4-in-O-D-Comp-x-1-8-in-MIP-Lead-Free-Brass-Compression-Adapter-Fitting-800729/207176820)*

Comment: LOVE IT!  will try as soon as I can get to a store!  too bad I have to Frankenstein it. thought they'd invent something like this.  my other thought was ditching the supplied hose and getting a vinyl supply hose (if it's long enough) and snip off the bottom end leaving it exposed for the barb on the foot pump.  top end would stay compression assuming it would come that way.  thanks!